# password protect homepage only in wordpress using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, passwords

I am trying to password protect the homepage of a website made on wordpress. If my domain is `mydomain.com` then if any one visits `mydomain.com`, he/she should get an authentication pop-up and for the rest of the page it should not (e.g. `mydomain.com/sample-page/allowed`). I am using the code below but no luck so far.

```
SetEnvIf Host "^mydomain.com$" passreq

AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=passreq
Satisfy any
```

Comment: This may not be possible because internally, all requests to WP are routed to one file (index.php). Password protecting URLs instead of files *may* be possible but I've never seen a working example.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks for quick reply, I am also thinking this but hope that some one has any solution. I guess i should redirect user from home page to any other allowed page. What do you think ?

Comment: There are password protection plugins for Wordpress, you could check those out. That said, I'm not sure what sense this makes - what good is a password proection mechanism that allows access to any page except the front page? After all, people can go to the other pages directly

Comment: Currently website is under development, Its home page is not ready but other pages are ready and they need to be publicly accessible. That's why i was after this solution. Plugins will not do the job because they are reverse of what i need, they only password protect single page. I was also trying the reverse method. I password protected the whole website and then allowed only some specific url, but they were not correctly displayed because password protection was not allowing to access the associated CSS, JavaScript etc.

Comment: `Plugins will not do the job because they are reverse of what i need, they only password protect single page.` but isn't that exactly what you want here?

Comment: I doubt it will not work on homepage. Let me find some plugin and see if it work, Many thanks for your time. Will wait for some more suggestion.

Comment: I have just seen some plugins, They are using wordpress built in privacy, password mechanism so basically it will allow only to restrict them from accessing content not the whole page. There is no effective htaccess base solution